# De-esser for Windows 8 audio output?

Tags: windows-8, firefox, audio, flash, speech

Lately I've been watching a lot of lectures online, but a good amount of them hurt my ears because of how sharp the professor pronounces any words containing "s". This is a very recognized problem for musicians and such, and sound engineers often use "de-essers" on speakers or singers to make the sound less harsh.

I'm wondering if there's a way to attach a de-esser to the Windows audio output, or to the output of a particular program (a Flash instance running in Firefox) much in the same way as Windows supports "enhancements" like "bass boost", or "loudness equalization" under the Hardware and Sound section of the Control Panel. Is this possible?